# write contents of one file to another file in the same folder in nsis

Tags: file, copy, nsis

I need help writing contents of one file to another in NSIS.
I have two files config1.config and config2.config with default settings in the same folder.I just want to clear contents of config2.config file and write all contents of config1.config to config2.config.
I am getting error in below code

```
 File /oname=c:\DataSubmissionToolFinal.war DataSubmissionToolFinal.war
```

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to copy all the contents of one file into another file in the same directory, following should work for you:

```
Section ""

Delete "config2.config"  ; deletes the previous config2.config 
Copyfiles "config1.config" "config2.config"

SectionEnd
```

And
What are you trying to do in this?

```
File /oname=c:\DataSubmissionToolFinal.war DataSubmissionToolFinal.war
```

And what error are you getting?

Comment: well, i tested it. And it works for me.
`outfile "Test.exe"
section ""
Delete file2.txt
Copyfiles file1.txt file2.txt
sectionend`

Comment: From the NSIS manual: "Fully-qualified path names should always be used with this instruction. Using relative paths will have unpredictable results." Internally CopyFiles uses SHFileOperation and MSDN has this to say about the destination: "Use fully qualified paths. Using relative paths is not prohibited, but can have unpredictable results." As long as you are only copying 1 file you can probably get away with including a filename in the destination.